# Pass major/minor number to post-build step of TFS XAML build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm not familiar with Team Foundation Server.  I'm modifying our build process to pass the major/minor version numbers to a script.  These numbers are set in the XAML build (which I didn't configure).  There is a post-build step in which a python script launches our Linux build through Jenkins.  How do I pass these major/minor version numbers to this script?  I've tried

**Post Build Command**
`c:\python27\python.exe`

**Post Build Command Args**
`-u "$(SourcesDirectory)\BuildScripts\BuildServerPostBuild.py" "VersionStr=major.minor"`

However, this revealed a major version is "major" and minor version is "minor."  So, how do I pass these to the script?  I'm not seeing something in the Visual Studio/TFS help.

Comment: What's the version of TFS are you using?

Comment: @cece my boss keeps us virtually on the cutting edge.  If I'm not mistaken, we're using TFS 2015.

Comment: @Cece Yes, we will be moving to something different.  The fellow who put this together has nothing good to say about the XAML stuff.  Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize TFS build template by adding InvokeProcess activity to invoke python.exe and add the argument. You can check this blog for more information:https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/versioning-assembly-during-tfs-build-2013/

Another way is to use TFS vNext build, which is more flexible to hook your own scripts into a build process. Check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/index